# web service call fails

Tags: c#, web-services

I have created a windows service application with C# with .Net 2.0, and added a web service as

```
http://localhost/postIncidents.ws.php?wsdl
```

It has the method "ReportIncident". I checked the windows service in local environment.
It worked. 
Before I deploy it I added below code to get the particular url from a setting file.

```
shids_client.shidsWebServer.ReportIncident r = new shids_client.shidsWebServer.ReportIncident();
r.Url = Constant.readUrl();
r.CallReportIncident(time,LocalIPAddress(),type,line);
```

After I deployed, I added the URL to my setting file as

```
      http://192.168.1.1/postIncidents.ws.php?wsdl
```

After I check it, it didn't work. the following error was in my log:

"Operation 'CallReportIncident' is not defined in the WSDL for this service"

---

if i remove it, then it will not show the wsdl xml. it will show only a rendered page.

Comment: Old style Web service or WCF style?

Comment: Can you post the WSDL?

Answer (score 0):

You use the ?wsdl flag so that Visual Studio can download the WSDL and generate the service proxy. When the proxy actually runs, it runs against http:///postIncidents.ws.php, not ?wsdl needed. So try removing ?wsdl from the URL.

Comment: if i remove it, then it will not show the wsdl xml. it will show only a rendered page.

Comment: what do you see if you try :       http://localhost/postIncidents.ws.php/ReportIncident

Comment: same error occurred.    http://192.168.223.1/sHidsUi/postIncidents.ws.php/ReportIncident-->Operation 'CallReportIncident' is not defined in the WSDL for this service

Comment: I'm assuming that because you were actually able to create the proxy using the wsdl, it is in fact defined. However, is this SOAP service implemented in .NET or PHP? If its PHP then it might be with the internals of that. Can you try a third party SOAP client (such as SoapUI) to see if you can test the service without the .net proxy?

Comment: also, another thing that comes to mind is that .php extension. On your dev local environment, IIS might be fine with it, but on a different IIS install, that might not be set up correctly.

Comment: I have deployed it in wamp server.

Comment: So to sum up, its a PHP SOAP service, deployed on Windows Apache. And there is a .NET application calling it. So in theory if both .NET and Apache/PHP adhere to the SOAP spec, there should be no problem. Which seems to be the case in your dev environment. It sounds like an environmental issue, what are the differences between your dev and other environment?

Comment: It is the same server. I have tested it locally and trying to deploy the windows service in a different PC and test the web service connectivity to the server.

Comment: I have tested in soap ui. it works. with "?wsdl". only my windows service is not working. please help

Comment: can you debug your service proxy and step down to the place where it actually pulls the service reference from the app.config? is it pulling up localhost or the 192 address?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29580/discussion-between-user851157-and-juan-ayala)